# How to parse JSON data from multiple URLs into multiple Activities

Tags: json

I am developing a shopping App. I need to parse JSON data to multiple Activities. I already parsed data into single activity by defining URL in MainActivity. 
*But the problem is, i need to parse data from multiple URLs. I am confused in programming for this process. Please suggest me to define URLs.*
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have missed at least one tag when you wrote this question. Consider mentioning what language and framework you are using.

Comment: I am coding in Java and Eclipse IDE with the android bundle @https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams